# How to avoid triggering Dash Interval event at every reload of the app

Tags: python, plotly-dash, dashboard, plotly-python

I have a Dash app running on a server, that contains an Interval call which triggers an event periodically. Essentially every time this event is triggered, a certain function is executed and it sends a summary file. The code is as follows on the app.py file:

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        dcc.Interval(id='interval-trigger', interval=3600*1000, n_intervals=0),
        html.H1(id='event-trigger', children=''),
    ]),
])

@app.callback(dash.dependencies.Output('event-trigger', 'children'),
              dash.dependencies.Input('interval-trigger', 'n_intervals'))
def trigger_event(n):
     check_summary()
```

At the moment this event is triggered every hour. The problem that I have is that every time this app is reloaded on the server by other people, the event gets triggered which is obviously outside of the period within which it should be triggered.

Is there a way to avoid having the event (Interval) being triggered every time the app reloads (mostly when other people open the Dash app on the server).

Comment: You could cache the result of your summary function. See https://dash.plotly.com/performance as a starting point.